# UDP Concurrent client recvfrom error

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets, udp

I am now doing concurrent socket programming with C/C++. I just made the server to receive a request from client and sending the response packets to clients. I use one thread to receive requests from Clients. when the server got a new request, a new thread will be create in order to send some packets to clients. However, the recvfrom in my client side always return the winsock error 10054 while my server is sending packets out to that particular client.

Comment: You're getting an "ICMP port unreachable" response, you should probably be handling that.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means the udp port is closed and you are receiving a packet on the closed port. For example in voip phone the client sends origport=12295 stating that please send the packet on this and will close the working port 32000
08:43:32.377 cip=172.x.23.225 sip=10.x.20.2 cport=32000 sport=32128 origport=12295

But if the server don't understand this and you still receive the packet on 32000 from server then client will show this error message

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/269058-ignoring-error-code-10054-for-udp/), it is a harmless error and you can just ignore it in the client.

Comment: How to ignore it?> I still got the recvfrom returning the value -1. Is it my buffer in recvfrom still got the message even though i got this error.